# Advantages of using inner functions(javascript)

Tags: javascript, function

this might not be a very specific question but I was wondering what are the advantages of using an inner function? I've recently started reading on closures (javascript) and they always refer to inner functions.

```
var pet = function(name) {   
  var getName = function() {
    return name;                          
  }
  return getName;           
}
myPet = pet('Vivie');
myPet();
```

Why would we not want to seperate the getName function and introduce a 'name' parameter so that we could call it independantly?

```
var pet = function(name){
  return getName();
}
function getName(name){
  return name;
}
```

Thank you, I am quite new to javascript

Comment: This is very context specific. You may not have access to `name` at the point of calling (and if you did have access, that would defeat the purpose altogether of that getter function). Sometimes you want to transform how a function operates, and you accept a function as a parameter and return a new "modified" function.

Comment: This is an example of how to implement a class in javascript. You want to have the getName function inside because it's a method of that 'class' and should only be visible inside that function in order to achieve encapsulation.

Comment: @PaulBota In that case though, the constructor wouldn't be returning a reference to the function; the function would be made a part of the constructed object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this article. [Simple guide to understand closure in JavaScript](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-closures-simplified-d0d23fa06ba4/)

I copied here a part of the code explained in the article.
Run this code snippet to see the behavior of the inner function.

```html
<script>

function outer() {

  var b = 10;
  var c = 100;
  
  function inner() {
  
    var a = 20;
    console.log("a= " + a + " b= " + b);
    
    a++;
    b++;
    
  }
  return inner;
}

var X = outer(); // outer() invoked the first time
var Y = outer();  // outer() invoked the second time
//end of outer() function executions

X(); // X() invoked the first time
X(); // X() invoked the second time
X(); // X() invoked the third time

Y(); // Y() invoked the first time

</script>
```